# Excel: Bulk insert to multiple cells

Tags: microsoft-excel

My data analysis script returns something like this as an output: [1.041, 2.497, 3.123, 1.123]. I want to present this data in an Excel spreadsheet, so I want to have a row with a first cell as 1.041, second cell as 2.497 etc.

Is there a way to insert all 4 values in a single step? (Instead of tediously copying and pasting 1.041, 2.497 , ... in four separate steps)

Comment: Where is the output from the script? A text file?

Comment: Yes, it's a text file

Comment: A single step might be a bit hard, but several steps for any number of values is possible. I would suggest using the Data Import Wizard and using the comma as delimiter to split the lines of values into the columns.

Comment: Which excel are you using? In excel 2010 you can go to data - get external data, from text, select the text file, delimited, using the comma as your delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

Given the output of the data analysis script is a text file the easiest way to translate this into Excel is by setting up a data connection.  Once setup, the data connection can be refreshed to import new data.

On the 'Data' tab in the ribbon choose 'From text file' then follow the wizard.  (There are lots of options here and there are many parameters.  It would take to long to go over them in this answer but there are many resources online such as: [How to import a text file into Excel 2010](http://www.exceldigest.com/myblog/2012/05/31/how-to-import-a-text-file-into-excel-2010/))

TWO OPTIONS
1. If you save the output data to DIFFERENT TXT files each times but use a single spreadsheet but you should leave, from the "Properties" window, the 'Prompt for file name on refresh' checked.

2. If you SAVE OVER the output data file then UNCHECK the 'Prompt for file name on refresh'

Below are some selected screen grabs but not the whole wizard

[image]

[image]

[image]